# Concurrent Browsers through Java's API for Sahi

Tags: java, concurrency, driver, sahi

I am utilizing Sahi Pro's sahi.jar package for Java. Normally, Sahi Pro allows the user to execute one test across concurrent instances of different web browsers through their [testrunner.bat file](https://sahipro.com/docs/using-sahi/playback-desktop.html).

I cannot find a similar method to implement in Java. Does anyone familiar with [Java's API for Sahi](https://sahipro.com/java/javadocs/overview-summary.html) know of a way to run concurrent browser tests through it? 
Thank you.